# Linq joining tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have following two tables

```
T1
==========
tid  pId    bId   desc
1    11     10    xyz
2    9      7     abc
3    11     9     tyy
```

and

```
T2
=========
id   bId   exp
1    10    main
2    9     front
3    10    front
4    8     top
5    10    main2
6    9     newM
```

My model class is

```
public class test
 {
   public int tid {get; set;}|
   public int bid {get; set:}
   public IEnumerable<T2> t2 {get; set;}

 }
```

I want to write linq query so that I can select list of test class

```
var records=(from c in T1 
             join y in T2 on c.bid equals y.bid
             where c.id==id
             select {
               ....
              });
```

I am kind of new to linq queries. Please let me know how I can write this query.
Thanks

Comment: I do not understand this line: "I want to write linq query so that for given pId I want to select tid, bid and also list of T2 where bId."

Comment: I changed it to "I want to write linq query so that I can select list of test class" Thanks

Comment: Is T1 also a IEnumerable in test class?

Comment: It looks to me like you're already written the query.  Are you looking for what to put inside the curly braces in the `select` clause?

Comment: You've got the linq, you only need to select the fields from c and y that you want in records.

Comment: There is no `id` field in `T1` but you are trying to filter off it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var records = (from t1 in T1
               join t2 in T2
               on t1.bid equals t2.bid
               where t1.id == id
               select new test { tid = t1.tid, bid = t1.bid });

foreach(var record in records)
{
    record.t2 = (from t2 in T2
                 where t2.bid == record.bid
                 select new T2 { id = t2.id, bid = t2.bid }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to group by `bId` and `tid` basically.

```
var records = (from c in T1
                join y in T2 on c.bId equals y.bId
                where y.id == id
                select new {c.bId, c.tid, y})
                .GroupBy(t => new { t.bId, t.tid })
                .Select(g => new Result { bid = g.Key.bId, tid = g.Key.tid, 
                          tests = g.Select(gg=>gg.y) }).ToList();
```